# running time of add(i, x) for dual array deque

Tags: java, data-structures

A DualArrayDeque represents a list using two ArrayStacks.

```
List<T> front;
List<T> back;

void add(int i, T x) {

    if (i < front.size()) {
        front.add(front.size()-i, x);
    } else {
        back.add(i-front.size(), x);
    }

    balance();

}
```

Ignore the running time of balance(). If `i < front.size()`, `add(i,x)` running time is `O(i+1)`. Shift 0-i elements to the left [`O(i)`] and assign ith element to x [`O(1)`]. Similarly, when `i > front.size()`, it is `O(n-i+1)`;

`front.size()` and `back.size()` do not differ by more than a factor of 3. In particular, `3 · front.size() ≥ back.size()` and `3 · back.size() ≥ front.size()`. Therefore, The running time is `O(1 + i)` if `i < n/4`, and `O(1 + n − i)` if `i ≥ 3n/4`;

My question is **when `n/4 <= i < 3n/4`, why the running time of `add(i,x)` is `O(n)`?**

PS: I am reading Open Data Structure http://opendatastructures.org/ods-java/2_5_DualArrayDeque_Building.html. I am very confused why it is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the text that you are referring. Your answer lies in the balance() function.

```
void balance() {
    int n = size();
    if (3*front.size() < back.size()) {
        int s = n/2 - front.size();
        List<T> l1 = newStack();
        List<T> l2 = newStack();
        l1.addAll(back.subList(0,s));
        Collections.reverse(l1);
        l1.addAll(front);
        l2.addAll(back.subList(s, back.size()));
        front = l1;
        back = l2;
    } else if (3*back.size() < front.size()) {
        int s = front.size() - n/2;
        List<T> l1 = newStack();
        List<T> l2 = newStack();
        l1.addAll(front.subList(s, front.size()));
        l2.addAll(front.subList(0, s));
        Collections.reverse(l2);
        l2.addAll(back);
        front = l1;
        back = l2;
    }
}
```

When 3*front.size() < back.size(), balance() is copying n/2-front.size() elements from back into l1, reversing it, copying all the elements of front into l1 and copying the remaining elements of back into l2.

Similarly when 3*back.size() < front.size(), balance() is copying n/2+1 elements from front into l1, copying the remaining elements of front into l2, reversing it and copying all the elements of back also into l2.

In both the above cases, balance() function is copying all the elements of front and back into l1 and l2 which takes O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where the split between the two backing arrays occurs at position 3n/4. So there are 3n/4 elements in the front array, and n/4 elements in the back array. Now what happens when someone calls add(i) where i=3n/4-1. That is, what happens when someone adds to the last element in the front array. Since the front arraystack is actually in reverse that's the same as adding to index 0 in an array stack: everything in that stack must be shifted by one to make room.

So worst case, if n/4 < i < 3n/4 we could be shifting 3n/4 elements which is O(n).